# ViewController class for Page Based Application (PageViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a PageViewController with two View controllers. Is it possible to create a custom class for ViewController to control behaviour? for instance, one of the ViewControllers has a button and I create a class for this ViewController to control the behavior of button click?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, of course this is possible (and indeed necessary). Is there anything specific you are struggling with?

Comment: Yes.  When I create a custom class and assign it to view controller via Identity Inspector, the respective view controller turns out black in simulator.